# Multiple instructions in select/when statement vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I've an assignement in which I've to describe an alu using vhdl in which our teacher asked us to use **select/when** statement.

I've almost done it but at some opcode the alu has to "return" **the msb and lsb of the signed and unsigned multiplication and division of the two input**.

Now my problem is that I can't manage to write **mutliple instruction** for **one when**.
When I try to compile, I get some kind "Syntax error".

Any of you have an idea how to do that?

Here is my entity

```
entity alu is
  port (
    a : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    opcode: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    res : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
  );
end entity alu;
```

And here is the architecture.

```
architecture RTL of alu is
  signal um : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
  -- Implémenter le fonctionnement
  with opcode select res <=
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) + unsigned(b)) when "0000",
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b)) when "0001",
    not a when "0010",
    a or b when "0011",
    a and b when "0100",
    a xor b when "0101",
    a when "0110", -- yet todo

    (um <= std_logic_vector(signed(a) * signed(b)); res <= um(31 downto 16)) when "0111",   -- at this line
    
    std_logic_vector(signed(a) * signed(b))(15 downto 0) when "1000",                       -- at this line
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b))(31 downto 16) when "1001",                  -- at this line
    std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b))(15 downto 0) when "1010",                   -- at this line
    a when "1011",
    b when "1100",
    x"DEAD" when others;
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You've included an entire concurrent assignment statement in the middle of a when clause. Put it somewhere else.

Comment: Provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're missing a context clause before the entity declaration, the complete architecture and specific error messages to provide a [mcve]. The result of a binary operator (here "\*") can't be sliced, there is no static name prefix (IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1, 8.5 Slice names), slice a call to the function implementing unsigned "*" instead. The assignment to um wants to be a concurrent statement or replaced by a slice of a function call to "\*" like the rest. See 10.5.4 Selected signal assignments for the syntax.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes I guess I saw that as a software and not as electronic simulation thank you!